# In Laravel I can get my username but I can't get my password

Tags: php, laravel

This code is not working in Laravel, because password is `hashed`, it is `bcryted`, how do I compare and get my us_id (which stands for username_id ), the one that tried to login but has the wrong password, do you have any suggestion. What I'm trying to do is very simple, I'm trying to understand if the user entered a wrong password but his/her username is right. I am beginner. sorry for that. I know this won't work, but what should I do to understand if the user entered a wrong password?

```
public function login(Request $request, Logs $logs)
{

    $password = $request->input('password');

    $myuser = \DB::table('users')->where('password', $password)->first();

    if (\Hash::check($password, $myuser->password)) {
        $logdata = $myuser->id;
        $logs->insert($logdata);
        return view('MainPages.example', ['pass' => $password]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this worked, the logic of your query is all wrong, it would fetch the first user whom had used the entered password.

Answer (score 1):

The password is hashed by Laravel, so use the `Hash::check()` method:

```
if (\Hash::check($password, $myuser1->password)) {
```

> The Laravel `Hash` facade provides secure Bcrypt hashing for storing user passwords. If you are using the built-in `LoginController` and  `RegisterController` classes that are included with your Laravel application, they will automatically use Bcrypt for registration and authentication.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing

Comment: thanks , But NO , i saved the password using bcrypt() , and i also tried that whay , first i converted the inputed password to bcrypt , then i made the comparison , but still , nothing :(( . i don't know what to do . i'm stuck here for several hours .

Comment: @Salamander when you're using `bcrypt`, you're using `Hash::make()` method to encrypt the password. Just try the code.

Comment: @Salamander use `Hash::check()`, I've updated the code like a minute ago, there was a typo.

Comment: How are you supposed to 'select'  a user with their password, when you're not encrypting it... Look closely.. https://i.imgur.com/ns8Jt6y.png

Comment: It's `null` because you're doing this `$myuser1 = User::where('password', $password)->first();`. Use username to fetch the user `$myuser1 = User::where('username', $username)->first();`

Comment: @Salamander if you remove that password query, this will work if you have a user with `username = $request->username` and if the password you enter is correct. Also, make sure you didn't change the app key after you've saved the user and his password.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Just semantically hashing != encrypting. If something is encrypted it is meant to be decrypted meaning revert to it's original state. Hashed string practically never can be reverted to original state. Everything else from answer and comments goes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect this to work.

Passwords are stored encrypted. Multiple people could theoretically have the exact same password, but none of them would look identical when stored. Therefore you don't know what to look for in the record, even if you know what password you are looking for because you don't know what salt was used for the particular record where it is stored.

You just can't retrieve a record on a password lookup like this. Rather, you have to retrieve the record first (based on some other key, eg. username or id) and then see if the password encrypts to match from the given password that has the ever important salt.

Comment: what i want to do is simply check when the user tries to login , his password is wrong , or his username is wrong , and i want to store that user Id in logs database . thats all . but this password is giving me headache , i tried everything . i know the password is there , but i don't know anyway to check if it is the password that is going wrong for the user

Comment: i want to right this authentication , i'm a beginner , but i really tried :(

Comment: @Salamander that's why you have to compare hashes, not passwords themsevles

Comment: @Octopus and i tried look it up using the user username . but it failed too . what do you suggest :( ?

Comment: @Salamander, first retrieve the entire record using only the username. Then use the password from that record as the second parameter in the hash() function as Alexey has show in his answer.

Comment: @Octopus i exactly did that , retrieve the record using username , but when i'm trying to get the password using that way , still nothing , but thanks for your answers , i don't know what to do really , i got headache .

Comment: @Salamander, are you saying there is nothing in the password field for that record? I'm not clear on what happened to you. Try asking a new question with that includes those steps.

Comment: @Octopus i have updated my question , please please take a look at it , do you have any suggestioin , what i'm trying to do is very simple , i'm trying to understand if the user entered a wrong password but his/her username is right . i am beginner . sorry for that  :( . i know this won't work , but what should i do to understand if the user entered a wrong password ?